# SQL: How to query items from one table that are not in another when the syntax is not the same?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question because I'm really bad at SQL. I understand basic functions but when
it gets a bit more complex, I'm completly lost.

here is what I have:
tables: tA, tB
columns: tA: refA tB: refB
basically refA and refB represent the same thing (some id of a form like xxx-xxx-xxx), but
refB can have information appended (like xxx-xxx-xxx_Zxxx or xxx-xxx-xxx Zxxx)

here is what I know how to do:
querying items that are in a table but not in another (when they are exactly the same)

```
select refA
from tA
where not exists (select *
from tB
where tB.refB = tA.refA
)
```

**What i want to do:**
I want a query that will list items from refA that are not in refB.
BUT, Problem is if I run a "simple" query with a NOT EXISTS like I just showed, it will return everything, 
because of the appends. so I thought about using some syntax like this:

```
SELECT refA
FROM tA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM tB
WHERE tB.refB LIKE CONCAT(tA.refA,'%'))
```

but... of course, it doesn't work.

Could someone show me how it should be done, and also explain how it works, so I can learn ?
Thanks in advance !

**edit: additional info**
I can't use a left() or something alike, because the ref format is similar but not always the same (varies in number of characters).
The only way to detect the end of the id before the append, is that there is either a blank space or an underscore.

**edit 2: data sample causing problems (MON, Jan. 10th)**

here is some actual data from the tables, which makes most answers people have given here
miss some results :/

in tA:
B20-60-04-6A-1
B20-60-04-6A-11
B20-60-04-6A-12
B20-60-04-6A-13

in tB:
B20-60-04-6A-11_XX
B20-60-04-6A-12_XX
B20-60-04-6A-13_XX

problem with mid(), left(), etc. is that if we check "B20-60-04-6A-1" (14 chars)
against the 14 first chars, it will return 3 positives, while in fact it is not in tB...

so, how can we proceed ?

Examples of data patterns in tA are like this:
(X, XYZ: charaters. x: alphanumerical)
Xxx-xx-xx-x
Xxx-xx-xx-xx
Xxx-xx-xx-xx-xx
Xxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-x
etc

examples of data patterns in tB:
Xxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-XYZ-xx Z xxx_XX
Xxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-XYZZxxx_XX
Xxx-xx-xx-xx-xx Z xxx_XX

XYZ are always the same 3 characters. When we do not have XYZ, there is always a blank space or an underscore.

so the string of data we compare should be trimmed according to this:
- from start to -XYZ string
- or, if no -XYZ in the string, from start to the first " " or "_"

I'd write that lightning fast in VBA, but in SQL... well, I'll give it a shot, but I'm really bad at it :D

Comment: chose an accepted answer since it's what got me working the fastest; however I'll have to check what Matt said about some occurrences being 'true' twice. Will check that a bit later but at least I've got a lot of solutions to try ! :)

Comment: +1 for stated desire to learn from the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first off, you need a function that will change refB to not have the appended information, so it can be compared properly with refA. There will be several approaches, but something like this should work:

```
Left(tb.RefB, InStr(Replace(tb.RefB+"_", " ", "_"), "_") -1)
```

That will convert any refB like "123-456 123 EXTRA STUFF" or "123-456_123_EXTRA_STUFF" into "123-456". That result should then be okay to compare directly with a refA.

EDIT: A short explanation of the expression above. What I'm doing is:

1. Adding an underscore to the end of refB, so that there's always at least one underscore (this copes for the case where refB is the same as refA, e.g. "123" becomes "123_")
2. Replacing all spaces in refB with underscores (the `Replace` function). Now we know that the separator is always an underscore, and we also know from step 1 that there will be at least one underscore.
3. Finding the location of the first underscore (the `InStr` function). This is the position where refB is split between refA and the additional stuff.
4. Grabbing all the characters between the start of the string and this first underscore, i.e. the part before the separator.

So, that gives you something like this:

```
select refA
from tA
where not exists (select *
from tB
where Left(tb.RefB, InStr(Replace(tb.RefB+"_", " ", "_"), "_") -1) = tA.refA
)
```

I would use this approach rather than comparing with wildcards, or trimming refB to match the length of refA, because of this scenario:

```
refA
====
123
123-456
123-456-789

refB
====
123-456-789_This_is_a_test
```

In this case, trimming or wildcard matching refA with refB will result in success for all refAs, because "123*", "123-456*" and "123-456-789*" *all* match "123-456-789_This_is_a_test".

Comment: seems to be a problem with the left() solution, indeed... another problem is, I just found some refB looking like "123-456-some-thing" :/

Comment: could you explain what "left(tb.refB, instr(replace(replace(tb.refB + "_", "_", "~"), " ", "~"), "~") - 1)" does, exactly ? why use "~" when this character isn't supposed to be in any record ? is it a special character ? in addition to testing for "-" or " " can i test for something like "-xyz" ?

Comment: @Christian I've simplified this further now I've had a bit more time to think about it, and added an explanation of what I'm doing.

Comment: ...but you may have to post more detailed explanations of the strange cases you're finding now, like "123-456-some-thing", as that's even more stuff to deal with! Some of the actual, real examples might be very helpful here so we can know what we're up against :)

Comment: I added some sample data.
I'll have to try your solution and adapt it to test for -XYZ too.

Comment: @Christian From what I can understand of your example data, this might head you in the right direction: Left(tb.RefB,InStr(Replace(Replace(tb.RefB+"_"," ","_"),"-XYZ", "_"),"_")-1)

Comment: ... and thanks a lot for your added explanations, now what you are doing is very clear !  
However, it takes care of 2 situations: having a " " separator or a "_" separator. Is there a way to add a 3rd situation  ("-XYZ") ?  
Given how SQL functions work, I don't see how this could be done, but maybe someone has an idea ? :s  
Edit: you just beat me to it. I'll try that, didn't think about imbrication !! I'll post the results

Comment: @Christian In that last comment (I think we posted simultaneously!) I've added an extra `Replace()` -- that replaces "-XYZ" with an underscore before trimming RefB to the first underscore, so assuming that -XYZ only appears in any tb.refB as a separator, that should do the job.

Comment: yep that's what happened. just ran the query but it returns absolutely no result. I'm debugging now to find out why.

Comment: seems to work ok. I forgot to do the actual test after the left() !
But sometimes it skips a result (ran a few times, not always the same. It seems pretty intensive on the db engine.). Yay access :/ But at least it works pretty much ok ! Thanks a lot for your help and explanations ! Best answer as it takes care of situations where we could have "false negatives".

Comment: @Christian Glad it seems to be working. Funny that Access is skipping results; I always found it fairly reliable once I got it to actually do something, regardless of the load (the last Access job I ran took around eight hours to process its data, so that was a pretty heavy load...)

Comment: when not moving the mouse or anything while it processes, it works without missing anything

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a `left()` function, if one exists in access? Like this:

```
SELECT refA
FROM tA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM tB
WHERE Left(tB.refB, Len(tA.refA)) = tA.refA)
```

If, as you said, you have to look for a space or underscore in the refA, you can use this:

```
SELECT refA
FROM tA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM tB
WHERE Left(tB.refB, Max(Instr(tA.refA, ' '), Instr(tA.refA, '_'))) = tA.refA)
```

Comment: I thought about it, but I can't :( 
Didn't mention it but the ref format is similar but not always the same (varies in number of characters).
The only way to detect the end of the id before the append, is that there is either a blank space or an underscore.

Comment: That may be, but in those cases your `like ...%` will fail as well, since it matches the same things :)

Comment: It shouldn't:  
If refA is "1234" and refB is "1234 app", "1234 app" is a match of "1234%". Or isn't it ? o_o

Comment: Well yes, but `Left(tB.refB, Len(tA.refA)) = refA` is also true.

Comment: yes ! like Keith mentioned. For some reason I didn't think about it (I'm really lost when it comes to sql...) and it seems like an easy solution, gonna try to make something out of it.

Comment: tried the 1st solution (using len) but for some reason access spits out "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." ... don't understand, since they are both strings :/

Comment: Hmm... did you get all your parentheses in the right places? :) Can you show me your query?

Comment: SELECT refB
FROM tB
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM tA
WHERE Left(tA.refA, Len(tB.refB)) = tB.refB);

Comment: looks like I inverted everything, maybe that's why ! will try again.

Comment: returns a bunch of results, and they indeed aren't in tB. So it seems to work as intended !

Comment: That's what I thought as well! :) By the way, I just tried it as well, and at first I got the same error you got, but then I saved the tB table, or _something_, and then it just worked. Yay access.

Answer (score 1):

So you want everything from A where not in B, but where only the start of B's id matches?

```
select refA
from tA
left outer join tB 
    on tA.refA = left( tB.refB, len(tA.refA)) --trim B's id to the length of A's
where tB.refB is null
```

Comment: the using of len seems like it should solve my problem easily... don't know how outer join works however. I'll get some documentation and try to make it work.

Comment: You might need to be careful, though; if there are A's with IDs "123-456" and "123-4567", which are both also in B, then you'll get *two* results back when looking for "123-456" like this.

Comment: but it shouldn't be a problem if we use "NOT EXISTS", I think ?

Comment: @Christian M see this explanation: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @Matt Gibson - good point, and that will still be a problem whether you use EXISTS or JOIN. Your way round it depends on the format of the ids - if they're a consistent length you'll be better off with a constant anyway. Same is true if the suffix is a consistent length.

Answer (score 1):

I think your suggestion will work in a slightly different format, generally the wild card in Access is *, unless you have set ANSI 92 mode, however you can use ALIKE with % in 'ordinary' mode.

EDIT : DIFFERENT IDEA

```
SELECT tA.refA
FROM tA
WHERE (((tA.refA) 
   Not In (SELECT Mid(tb.RefB,1,Len(ta.RefA)) FROM tb)));
```

Comment: I tried something alike but it returned an error so I tried just part of the query to try to "debug" it, but it failed :/

SELECT *   
FROM tA, tB  
WHERE tA.refA LIKE tB.refB & '*'  

returns syntax error (lack of operator)

Comment: it... seems to work. Returns no result (if my collegues did they job right, it shouldn't return any result, so it seems right). Just to be sure I understand the query right: when we write that, sql actually takes colum refA from row 1 from tA, and compares it to EVERY row in tB (with the trimmed refB column) ? and then repeats the same for every row in tA ?

Comment: I tested before I posted, and it worked for me. Perhaps you could post a small set of test data? AFAIK, to see what you are comparing, you can use: `SELECT Mid(tb.RefB,1,Len(ta.RefA)) AS CompList
FROM tb, ta;`

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the schema. Your second table should have two columns, one containing the first part of the identifier, the other containing the second; if the column was the primary key first, just create a unique multi-column index and disallow NULL values.

You can also add a foreign key constraint this way, and/or optimize the comparisons by introducing a surrogate key in the first table and referencing that from the second.

If you do not have an index on the substring you are trying to match, you will end up with a full scan for each value you are looking for, this is hideously expensive.

Comment: this is a one-time action and I'm using SQL to run a query on data because it seems like the easiest way, but actually it isn't a database. I just put a bunch of data in access to run some queries on it - maybe there is a better way / application to do this, but I don't know about it...

Answer (score 0):

This is valid syntax and close to the syntax you say you want to write:

```
SELECT refA 
  FROM tA
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                     FROM tB
                    WHERE tB.refB ALIKE tA.refA & '%'
                  );
```